# AT command on Wavecom GSM modem

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim-card, hyperterminal

I put this script in a Hyperterminal console.

```
AT+CNMI=1,1,0,1,0
OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
OK
+CMTI: "SM",1
AT+CMGR=1
+CMGR: "REC UNREAD","+33659382587",,"12/08/22,21:42:28+08"
Coco
OK
AT+CMGD=1
```

My promblem is the console freeze and I get no response when I sent the command `AT+CMGD=1`
( this command deletes the SMS #1 ), but in my case the delete action doesn't work.

What could be the reason ?

Thanks.

Comment: What would happen if a new incoming message is read twice to make sure its *unread* status is changed to *read*, then finally delete it?

Comment: I would also try to read it twice to see if something happened to it. Also possibly enable `AT+CMEE=2`. 27.005 does not say anything about AT+CMGD being abortable or not, but have you tried aborting the command?